# Magento 2 execute php bin/magento setup:upgrade without command prompt

Tags: magento2

I am running a Magento 2 website on my mac locally.

My problem is that I'm having problems with my mac setup ad i'm not about to run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

from my terminal.

My question is...I there's any other way to do the same as: php bin/magento setup:upgrade or php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy without using the Terminal?

Comment: is it throws any error while run setup command?

Comment: Check for PHP path & give inputs regarding error message

Comment: Do you use MAMP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you install a custom version of PHP in your local environment (MAMP?).  In this case, you need use full path to PHP executable to run Magento cli.

For example for MAMP I use
`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/bin/php bin/magento`